# Using Serverless Typescript plugin changes output structure when importing shared files

Tags: typescript, serverless, serverless-plugins

I have the following folder structure for a project running `serverless-plugin-typescript`:

```
<root>
  - services
    - common
    - sample-service
```

`sample-service` houses the serverless.yml and all endpoints. `common` hosts a few entities/services/utilities/etc. When I import a file from `common` into `sample-service` and then run the offline or package command, the output folder structure changes from this (which is what I want):

```
<build root>
  - endpoints
    - ...files
```

To this (which is what I don't want):

```
<build root>
  - common
    - ...files
  - sample-service
    - endpoints
      - ...files
```

If I try to hit the API endpoint, I get an error saying it can't find my handler file (since it is in the `sample-service/endpoints` directory instead of the root `endpoints` directory). I can work around this in the case of `serverless-offline` by passing the `--location` param and specifying the `sample-service` folder. But when I deploy this to AWS, I have the same issue of it not finding the endpoint since it is a folder deeper than it should be.

I have tried using Typescript project references, but have not had much luck. I have also tried using `serverless-webpack`, but unfortunately there is a pretty large memory leak in it which is why I have moved on to trying a different build system.

Does anyone have any insight into how I could change the configuration of either Typescript or the serverless plugin to mimic the build structure I am looking for (the first one)? Or maybe I didn't implement project references the right way?

Comment: Would you include your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Also, you may have seen this already https://forum.serverless.com/t/file-foo-ts-is-not-under-rootdir-rootdir-is-expected-to-contain-all-source-files/9669 but it looks like it might be impossible with prisim's `serverless-plugin-typescript`